# How did Auguste Bravais come up with the regression line?

Tags: regression, history

I am new to statistics and linear regression and I came across the face that auguste bravais discovered regression line but didn't realize it.

> Auguste Bravais (1811-1863), professor of astronomy and physics, is
> probably best known for his work in crystallography (Nelson, 1998).
> With respect to error theory, he is best known for a paper he wrote in
> 1846 titled "Analyse mathématique sur les probabilités des erreurs de
> situation d'un point" [translated: "Mathematical analysis on the
> probability of errors of a point"]. This work is renowned for being
> the very first mathematical exposition of the theory of correlation.
> Pearson (1896), later to recall these remarks, said that it was
> Bravais who first discussed the fundamental theorems of the
> correlational calculus. In his famous paper of 1846, Bravais,
> mathematically, not empirically, found the equation of the normal
> surface for the frequency of error. Using both analytic and geometric
> methods, Bravais also essentially found what would eventually be
> coined "regression line." He did so through investigating how the
> various elliptical areas of the frequency surface vary given various
> directly observed quantities. Through this, he found the line of
> regression, but, in essence, did not realize it, and thus could not
> "make the leap" (Walker, 1929) necessary to claim the discovery of
> correlation or regression

[image]

My question is how did he use "various elliptical areas of the frequency surface" to come across the regression line? I don't understand it at all. Please use diagrams if you can. Not too much complex maths too cause I am a newbie. Just explain simply how that works.

Comment: This question might be better answered if it were migrated to the SE History of Science and Mathematics blog.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on the history of Mathematics or calculus, but intuitively I gather the following.  Suppose we have a point (point 'O' (presumably named for the origin)).   Around this point is an "error cloud" of possible places where the point could actually lie, forming an ellipse, which would be horizontally placed (unlike the diagram above). Point "M" is 'M' units on the y-axis away from the origin.  The ellipse would then be tilted up so that the right end of the ellipse intersects with a horizontal line drawn out from point "M".  This would be the regression line maybe?   But point "M" would need two coordinates, both y and x, so I think more information is needed.